# How to set icon on a programmatically created jquery button

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic

Hi I am trying to create a button dynamically and unable to get the icon on the button. I am unable to get the button to show icon. I would appreciate any help. How do I set close icon on the removeBtn button widget.

```
var a = [{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "50894875744e80aa5fa59853"
},
"name": "Test 1",
"color": "#b63e3e",
"propertyNames": ["Notes"]},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "50894afe744e80aa5fa59854"
},
"name": "Test 2",
"color": "#413bb6",
"propertyNames": ["Notes"]},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "50894c23744e80aa5fa59855"
},
"name": "Test 3",
"color": "#95eba5",
"propertyNames": ["Notes"]}];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

  var button = document.createElement('span');
  button.className = 'color-button';
  button.style.backgroundColor = a[i].color;

  var selectionItem = document.createElement('li');
  selectionItem.id = a[i]._id.$oid;
  selectionItem.className = "ui-widget-content";
  selectionItem.appendChild(button);

  selectionItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a[i].name));
  $('#id1').append(selectionItem);

  var removeBtn = $('<button/>',
            {
                    click: function(){
                    alert(this.parentNode.id);
                }
            });
  removeBtn.css("float","right");
  $("#"+a[i]._id.$oid).append(removeBtn);
}​
```

Here's the jsFiddle link to the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/vivsriva/VmEeR/5/

Comment: Where is your close icon, If you want an image there than create a class with that image in background and add that class on button tag. or simple 'X' symbol than add `.text("X");` to button.

Comment: You doing it wrong ... there's not much jQuery here ... lol

Comment: Yograj: I want to use the **ui-icon-close** but don't know how to set the class.

Comment: SpYk3HH: Please let me know, what I can do to improve it. I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a pointer to help you out.  This is your code with more jQuery and includes jQueryUI's Close icon on your close button:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var button = $("<span />").addClass("color-button").css({ "background-color": a[i].color }),
        selectionItem = $("<li />").prop({ id: a[i]._id.$oid }).addClass("ui-widget-content").css({ "background-color": a[i].color }).text(a[i].name).prepend(button);

    $('#id1').append(selectionItem);

    var removeBtn = $("<button />").css({ "float": "right", "margin-top": ".1em", "width": "1em" }).appendTo($("#"+a[i]._id.$oid));

    removeBtn.button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-circle-close' }, text: false })
    .click(function(e) {
        alert(this.parentNode.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks SpYk3HH. This is what I needed. Appreciate your help.

Comment: NP, glad I could help out, I rewrote  in full on jQuery syntax mimicking your code (with the addition of the .button call) hoping that you could compare your code to mine and see how jquery really simplifies JS.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be adding specific `class` with background-image to each button.

```
removeBtn.addClass('btn1');
```

And having CSS like:

```
button.btn1 { 
   background-image: url('yourimage')
}
```

Comment: Michal: thanks. Yes it will work. Is there a way to use **ui-icon-close** css class to set the icon option for the button widget?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
removeBtn.addClass('button-image').css("float","right");

.button-image 
{ 
   background-image: url('imageurl')
}
```